# r heatmap.2: preventing some matrix rows from manipulation in dendrogram

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, heatmap, dendrogram

I analyze certain data on multiple observations with several variables and visualize them via heatmaps, performing rows and columns rearrangement with clustering and dendrogram building. I use `heatmap.2()` function from R's  gplots library. However certain rows (typically, several last ones) of observations are to be excluded from the analysis, since they are some partial sums or so, but they need be included in the dendrogram on their place. That is I need to perform clustering on data without taking into account these rows for scaling etc, but next to include them on the last positions with conserved coloring scheme. Here is the minimal example of data and manipulations

```
# load library and create some data
library(gplots)
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))(n = 299)
df<-read.csv(text="experiment,var1,var2
1,5,4
2,3,2
3,2.3,1
4,3,4
sum1,3,5
sum2,4,5")

# arrange data so that it has the structure of datamatrix with original names
rname<-df[,1]
df<-df[,-1]
rownames(df)<-rname
df.matr<-data.matrix(df)
```

Next I build the dendrogram with clustering only by observations (rows) and custom color palette. The scaling is performed over columns.

```
heatmap.2(df.matr,cellnote=df.matr,scale="column",col=my_palette,trace="none",density.info="none",notecol="black",dendrogram="row",Colv="NA")
```

Here is the result:
[image: dendrogram and heatmap]

As it can be seen, the last rows, `sum1` and `sum2`, took part in clustering rearrangement; supposedly they were also used for computing averages and deviations for data scaling. For some reasons this may be undesirable (these rows may be already partial sums, or come from other population); however they need be included and visualized on the same footing in the final dendrogram. I could drop these rows before analysis, but how to insert them back on place? Or maybe there is some in-built solution in the package itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possible solution is to use package **pheatmap**. I would remove rows `sum1` and `sum2`, build a dendrogram, then add `sum1` and `sum2` as an annotation on top of heatmap: [heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaQS5.png) You also can change color of annotation bar to match colors used in the heatmap.